# DOC to PDF conversion PHP library

Tags: php, file-conversion

There are many DOC to PDF conversion libraries out there but all with limitations. Is there any library which does it for free. By **free** I mean ***no watermarks, no footer/header***. I am not bothered about the number of conversions daily but still it would be good if its around **15-20** a day.

**NOTE:** I am on a shared hosting **plus** no frameworks.

Comment: zend livedocx is one of the option

Comment: No frameworks.. Forgot to mention.

Comment: It's a library(third party which uses zend some functionality).

Comment: Alright. Can you show me an example of how to go about using it?

Comment: if you searched on google then you will get example and documentation both

Comment: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zendservice.livedocx.html

Comment: Going through it. Any other lib you know of? By the way http://www.phplivedocx.org doesnt open.

Comment: Nope. others have there restriction. this is best

Comment: So to use this lib would I have to use the Zend framework?

Comment: no just put that whole folder in your code directory and code based on example

Comment: Ok. Can you write down the example and the process so that I can upvote you?

Comment: @Anant forgive me if I am wrong but I see that this library merges template and data to produce the pdf but what I want to do is directly convert a ready doc/x file to pdf.

Comment: An old post but just to share another option: <a href="https://gist.github.com/groupdocscloud/52c581e5d4cbfafe60dc0f41a88a8c55#file-conversion_php_convert_to_pdf-php">GroupDocs.Conversion Cloud REST API</a>. It converts documents without any third-party app and with high fidelity.